# bash: Searching with ls

Tags: bash

Is there a bash command that can be used as Spotlight or an option with `ls` that only prints files containing certain text? I want to be able to open Terminal and type something `ls -SOMEOPTION filename` and find all the files that have `filename` in their name, and this option could be used with `-R` and it would work as a replacement for Spotlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all files which **contain** a certain string, you can use just grep on its own:

`grep -R /path/to/directory "myword"`

In the example above, `"myword"` is what you're looking for, and `/path/to/directory` is the directory you want to search through. `-R` tells `grep` to run a recursive search (i.e. to start at the path you specified, and go into each subdirectory in there).

**EDIT**

I've re-read your question and I think you're looking for how to find files that have a certain filename. For this use:

`find /path/to/directory -name "*glob*" -print`

where `/path/to/directory` is where you want to start your search (and `find` will also look in the subdirectories) and `"*glob*"` is a full or a partial file name that you want to look for. Please note, you can use wildcards (`.` and `*` for any single and any multiple characters match, respectively) in the glob. As a variation to this, you can use, as proposed by others:

`find /path/to/directory -name "*glob*" -exec ls -la {} \;`

in the above, what you put after the option `-exec` is any UNIX command with paramteres (in this case `ls -la`). The `{}` will be substituted by the file name `find` finds, and the `\;` is a termination string.

**EDIT 2**

Please note, the commands above give you similar results to Spotlight, but they don't use Spotlight at all.

If you'd like to use Spotlight from command line, you can use `mdfind` command, which is a command-line interface for Spotlight. Typing `mdfind` on its own will give you a quick help for using it with a few examples. `man mdfind` will give you a more detailed manual for it.

Essentially `mdfind` takes a search string (and optional modifiers) as it's argument and it's the same as you would type in Spotlight's text field when using it in a GUI.

Answer (score 5):

```
 find . -type f -name "*filename*" -exec grep -il 'mywordinthefile' {} \;
```

- `find` search for file recursively in a directory.
- First parameters is the directory you want to look in. Here it's `.` so the current directory. You could use `~/Documents` for example or any other directories.
- `-type f-` option is to only return files, not directories.
- `-name` option takes a pattern to find specifics filenames.
- `grep` is used here to find the word/pattern you want in the files found by `find`.

Comment: I copied the command into Terminal, I replaced myword with "test" because I have a file called test.txt in the directory, but I get no output.

Comment: -exec grep is only needed if you ant to find something in the file. For the file name, replace the `-name`

Answer (score 0):

To find files with a specific string in the filename, use

```
    find . -type f -name '*<filename>*' 2> /dev/null
```

Substitute `<filename>` with the string that you would like to look for in the filename.
The redirection at the end is to avoid printing errors when certain files/folders are not accessible.

---

You can put this command in a shell script, called say, *lsf* that would contain the following:

```
find . -type f -name "*$1*" 2> /dev/null
```

Then make it executable using

```
chmod +x lsf
```

---

You can also put this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file instead of a shell script as described above (the command is still named lsf here):

```
myls()
{
    find . -type f -name "*$1*" 2> /dev/null
}
alias lsf=myls
```